# Java code issues using eclipse IDE (beginner programmaer)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, console, printf

I'm in a beginner programming course for my college (Java), our assignment is to output exactly what's in the picture below to the console using eclipse IDE.  I was wondering how I can include the "$" character next to the purchase prices? I couldn't figure it out without messing things up.  Also, I would like any feedback on my code and what I can do to make it better.  Thanks.  This is what I have done so far for this assignment:

[Screenshot of assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxZgj.png)

My code so far:

```
public class PurchaseReport
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        double shirt=21.99;
        double pants=49.97;
        double shoes=89.50;
        double belt=19.99;
        double coat=129.95;
        double tot=311.40;
   
        
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Purchase Report");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.printf("Shirt: %26.2f%n%n", shirt);
        System.out.printf("Pants: %26.2f%n%n", pants);
        System.out.printf("Shoes: %26.2f%n%n", shoes);
        System.out.printf("Belt: %27.2f%n%n", belt);
        System.out.printf("Coat: %28.2f", coat);
        System.out.printf("%n%n");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.printf("Total: %27.2f", tot);

        
    }
}
```

This is what my code outputs to the console:
[console output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzTbn.png)

Comment: still haven't upvoted or accepted the answer that worked

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see the $ sign, next to the purchase price then you can try this solution

```
    public class PurchaseReport
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        double shirt=21.99;
        double pants=49.97;
        double shoes=89.50;
        double belt=19.99;
        double coat=129.95;
        double tot=311.40;
   
        
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Purchase Report");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.printf("Shirt: %26s%n%n",String.format("$%1.2f",shirt) );
        System.out.printf("Pants: %26s%n%n", String.format("$%1.2f",pants));
        System.out.printf("Shoes: %26s%n%n", String.format("$%1.2f",shoes));
        System.out.printf("Belt: %27s%n%n",String.format("$%1.2f",belt) );
        System.out.printf("Coat: %28s",String.format("$%1.2f",coat) );
        System.out.printf("%n%n");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.printf("Total: %27s", String.format("$%1.2f",tot));

        
    }
}
```

output look like:
[image]

Comment: this is not how american money is formatted, the dollar sign comes before the number

Comment: do you want to see at the beginning?

Comment: Yeah dollar sign before the number.  Thanks!

Comment: answer updated, so i think it will serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Create a NumberFormat instance, and print your variables as shows in the printf below:

```
NumberFormat nf=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.printf("Shirt %36s", nf.format(shirt));
```

Note, you can repeat the printf statement, but you only need one NumberFormat instance for the whole class, hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

You can add $ symbol in the print statement
Like
System.out.println("Shirt: %$26.2f%n%n", shirt);
this way you will get $ in your output.

Comment: Please ensure you fully validate your answer. As the above comment states, your answer does not compile and is thus incorrect.